# How to get data from Local Emulator Suite (Realtime Database) in C# (Xamarin.Forms) using FirebaseDatabase.net?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I installed Local Emulator Suite on my PC. It works, but I can't get any data from it in my C# code.

```
var firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("http://127.0.0.1:9000/?ns=NAMESPACE_NAME");

var data = await firebaseClient.Child("Theme_1/theme_name").OnceSingleAsync<string>();
```

I tried to replace in code usual URL ("https://SOMENAME.firebaseio.com/") to "localhost" or "http://127.0.0.1/" or "http://127.0.0.1:9000/?ns=NAMESPACE_NAME" but it doesn't work.

If I trying to get data using REST API (http://127.0.0.1:9000/?ns=NAMESPACE_NAME.json), the responce is:

```
{
  "error" : "Invalid Firebase database name"
}
```

How can I get/set data from Local Emulator Suite in my code?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_rtdb#instrument_your_app_to_talk_to_the_emulators

Comment: Have you tried using 10.0.2.2 as ip address  just as the doc said?